# Webscraping a Table that does not use <table> (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to programming so I apologize if this is actually simple. I've got a very basic knowledge of Python and have been trying to learn how to extract the table seen here on this website: https://rotogrinders.com/grids/nfl-targets-1402017?site=draftkings. The problem is that the Table is not set up as a traditional HTML table but is actually made from `<div>`s and seem to be populated via a script? I've been searching around trying my hardest to find a similar situation that was solved but I'm not sure if I'm searching correctly. Here is my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://rotogrinders.com/grids/nfl-targets-1402017?site=draftkings")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'bat'})

print(table.prettify())
```

I did not get very far since I ran right into this problem. If you know of a possible solution or an example I can learn from please let me know.

Comment: You should use a web crawler like Selenium or scrapy instead of requests if the table is populated by script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation where `selenium` comes handy, combined with `BeautifulSoup`. Besides these two, usually you need to carefully inspect elements using your browser.

In this case, I used `Firefox` (which requires `geckodriver` to be properly installed and placed in the appropriate location), but you can use `Chrome` or whatever your browser of choice is, as well.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from collections import OrderedDict
import more_itertools

# open Firefox to get the data

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://rotogrinders.com/grids/nfl-targets-1402017?site=draftkings')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
driver.quit()

# extract data from BeautifulSoup object

player_data = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'rgt-col'})
text = [y.text for x in player_data for y in x.descendants if y.name == 'div']

indices_to_delete = [i for i in range(0, len(text), 250)]
keys = [text[k] for k in indices_to_delete]

new_text = [x for x in text if not x in keys]
text = list(more_itertools.sliced(new_text, 249))
new_text = list(zip(*text))

# build the dict

players = OrderedDict()

for x in new_text:
    y = list(zip(keys, x))
    for key, val in y:
        if key == 'Player':
            players[val] = {}
            current_player = val
        else:
            players[current_player][key] = val
```

... so, when you `print(players)`, you get a nice OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict([
    ('DeAndre Hopkins', {
        'Salary': '$6200', 
        'Pos': 'WR', 
        'Opp': 'NEP', 
        'Team': 'HOU', 
        'GP': '2', 
        'Targets': '29', 
        'RzTar': '3', 
        'PoW Tar': '48.33%', 
        'Week 1': '16', 
        'Week 2': '13', 
        'Week 3': '\xa0', 
        'Week 4': '\xa0', 
        'Yards': '128', 
        'YPT': '4.41', 
        'Rec': '14', 
        'Rec Rate': '48.28%'}), 
    ('Dez Bryant', {
        'Salary': '$6800', 
        'Pos': 'WR', 
        'Opp': 'ARI', 
        'Team': 'DAL', 
        'GP': '2', 
        'Targets': '25', 
        'RzTar': '5', 
        'PoW Tar': '28.74%', 
        'Week 1': '9', 
        'Week 2': '16', 
        'Week 3': '\xa0', 
        'Week 4': '\xa0', 
        'Yards': '102', 
        'YPT': '4.08', 
        'Rec': '9', 
        'Rec Rate': '36.00%'}
     ) ... ])
```

... which means you can do something like:

```
>>> players['DeAndre Hopkins']
{'Salary': '$6200', 'Pos': 'WR' ... }
```

Ta-da!

Comment: This is incredible, thank you so very much! I definitely have a TON to learn. Time to catch up on my regular expressions among other things haha. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I updated the answer, check it out, now you get all the data!

Comment: You are a serious godsend my friend, thank you so much! I'm still a newbie when it comes to all of this so this looks like hieroglyphics at the moment, any suggestions on where to look to start trying to understand how you did this? Again, I really appreciate this!!!!

Comment: Well, there really isn't much to it. So besides `selenium` and `BeautifulSoup`,  you might want to check list comprehensions out (they are really just clever looking for-loops (admittedly, usually faster)). Besides that, you might want to learn about `zip()`, as well. I also took advantage of `more_itertools` module to slice the data to equal parts. You might want to add a bunch of  `print()`'s throughout the code in order to see what is happening. I'm sure you will find it easy once you get the hang of it! Keep going.